# Issues while Integrating Google assistant with my app

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I am trying to integrate google assistant to my fitness app so that when the user says "Start my workout on xyz app" my app starts. I followed the video here : 
https://developers.google.com/actions/app/

and added this to my manifest :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/actions"/>
```

Then added these details to my actions.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.START_EXERCISE">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://xyz.in{?exercise}">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter = "exercise.name"
                urlParameter = "exercise"
                />

        </fulfillment>
    </action>

</actions>
```

Still not getting desired results. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: This feature is under developer preview.

Comment: Yes, but it is available for development. As mentioned in IO/19

Comment: Can you add more detail on what's going wrong?

Comment: After adding the above details as mentioned in the docs and IO video it should work. After saying on assistant to "start my workout" it gives option of Fit and strava app but not of my app. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria you will need to say "start my workout with [app name]" to trigger via App Actions (without the app name it will trigger a more generic intent which is not App Actions, although there probably is a way to handle that with your app as well but i'm not sure what that is)

Comment: @AdamK I tried with app name too. It is not working. Also I tried the intent of Alarm and that seems to work fine, It is detecting my app, but that was just a trial basis of understanding what i have done wrong.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria I would suggest you try the sample app first and get that working (which also uses the fitness intents): https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/

Comment: Its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger the action using the App Actions Test Plugin in Android Studio:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12322-app-actions-test-tool

Once you've installed the plugin, you'll find it under 'Tools' and you can define an invocation name for your app + parameters.

From the on, you can trigger it saying "ok google, start my workout on xyz app"

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the issue is exactly? Did you get an error creating the preview using the test plugin? I found the plugin's error messages super helpful in setting up my app action.